# How to add css class to an element inside nav element

Tags: css, nav

I have a `<nav>` element on my page that contains couple of `<div>` elements and one of the divs contains a number of images. I want to add a border to the images so I have added a class to the css file:

```
.img-cls
{
     border: solid blue 1px;
}
```

Now if I add `class="img-cls"` to any image on the page, it adds a border, but if I add the same to any image inside `<nav>`, nothing changes. Can anyone help me fix the issue?

Below is my html:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"
         role="navigation">

        <div id="divContainer" class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

            </div>
            <div id="navbarContent" class="collapse navbar-collapse">

            </div>

            <div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">ID</span>
                    <input type="text" id="txtID" class="form-control"
                           placeholder="Enter your id here" />
                </div>
                <br />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
                    Submit Data
                </button>
                <br />
                    <img src="images/DOS.png" class="img-cls"/>
                    <img src="images/SR.png" class="img-cls"  />
                    <img src="images/RFI.jpg" class="img-cls"  />
            </div>


        </div>
    </nav>

</form>
```

Comment: A bit more code please. I love code

Comment: I'm taking a stab at saying you need to use `!important`, but without seeing any `HTML`, it's impossible to provide a precise answer.

Comment: So in your nav tag there are `div`s and `img`s am I getting this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably another rule for images inside nav that prevents the border. But you can add `!important` to your rule:

```
.img-cls
{
     border: solid blue 1px !important;
}
```

This should override the other rule (unless it also has `!important` in it)

ADDITION/EDIT:

You can also set up a rule for images inside your `<nav>`element:

```
nav img { border: solid blue 1px };
```

Comment: I didn't ding you but there are probably better ways to solve this than using the  dreaded `!important` directive.

Answer (score 1):

try this, all your child images will have the border

```
    <style>
      .bordered_images img
      {
           border: solid blue 1px;
      }

      nav .border{
        border: solid red 5px; 
      }
      nav .bigborder{
        border: solid purple 10px; 
      }
    </style>


          <div class="bordered_images">
            <img class="" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" alt="">
            <img class="" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" alt="">
            <div class="anotherdiv">
              <img class="" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" alt="">

              <div class="onemore">
                <img class="" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" alt="">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


    <nav>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" alt="" class="border">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" alt="" class="">
      <div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" alt="" class="bigborder">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" alt="" class="">
      </div>
    </nav>



  <style>
      .img-cls {
        border: solid red 5px; 

      }

  </style>

  <h1>THE FORM</h1>
  <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"
           role="navigation">

          <div id="divContainer" class="container">
              <div class="navbar-header">

              </div>
              <div id="navbarContent" class="collapse navbar-collapse">

              </div>

              <div>
                  <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon">ID</span>
                      <input type="text" id="txtID" class="form-control"
                             placeholder="Enter your id here" />
                  </div>
                  <br />
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
                      Submit Data
                  </button>
                  <br />
                      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" class="img-cls"/>
                      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" class="img-cls"  />
                      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" class="img-cls"  />
              </div>


          </div>
      </nav>

  </form>
```

Let me know if you solve your problem.

Here the example
[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGbGop)

Comment: Actually I do not want all images in a div to have border, just the ones I specify. But I did try your code and it did not work for me

Comment: I edited my code, now just add border some child images. 
[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGbGop)

Comment: i updated the codepen with your code, it is at the bottom, it works for me. [Check this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGbGop)

Answer (score 0):

The problem definitely in css priority.
Try to access your images with next selector (which has more priority than mentioned above.)

```
nav div img.img-cls, nav img.img-cls
{
     border: solid blue 1px;
}
```

Comment: But doesn't he want to get the border on nav img.img-cls as well?

Comment: From question it looks like that selector should suit well, because `nav` contains `divs` which contain `img`...

Comment: But he also wants to target `img`s that are direct descendents of nav